# Print multiline strings side-by-side

Tags: python

I want to print the items from a list on the same line.
The code I have tried:

```
dice_art = ["""
 -------
|       |
|   N   |
|       |
 ------- ""","""
 -------
|       |
|   1   |
|       |
 ------- """] etc...

player = [0, 1, 2]
for i in player:
    print(dice_art[i], end='')
```

output =

```
ASCII0
ASCII1
ASCII2
```

I want output to =

```
ASCII0 ASCII1 ASCII2
```

This code still prints the ASCII art representation of my die on a new line.  I would like to print it on the same line to save space and show each player's roll on one screen.

Comment: Show the output and intended output. Also show the values of the list elements. We need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Comment: I've made the edits as requested.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity. I have updated with more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the elements of `dice_art` are multiline strings, this is going to be harder than that.

First, remove newlines from the beginning of each string and make sure all lines in ASCII art have the same length.

Then try the following

```
player = [0, 1, 2]
lines = [dice_art[i].splitlines() for i in player]
for l in zip(*lines):
    print(*l, sep='')
```

If you apply the described changes to your ASCII art, the code will print

```
 -------  -------  ------- 
|       ||       ||       |
|   N   ||   1   ||   2   |
|       ||       ||       |
 -------  -------  -------
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This works for the most part except the top lines move one closer for each printed die.  Can you clarify how I should remove new lines from the beginning of each string.

Comment: @Ozixic that's exactly why I advised to *"make sure all lines in ASCII art have the same length"* ;) Add a single space at the end of the first line in each ASCII art. If you have full control over how those multi-line strings are defined, you can simply place `'''` and ` ------- ` on the same line. Otherwise you could modify the code slightly: `[dice_art[i].strip('\n').splitlines() ...]`

Comment: Thanks! I got the alignment correct.  Can you explain to a noob how this for loop works with zip? I looked up zip in the docs and i'm still confused.

Comment: @Ozixic have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/2301450) answer yet? The example at the bottom should explain how `zip` works with multiple arguments. The `*` in `zip(*lines)` simply unpacks positional arguments out of `lines` list. In this case it's equivalent to `zip(lines[0], lines[1], lines[2])`

Answer (score 4):

The fact that your boxes are multiline changes everything.

Your intended output, as I understand it, is this:

```
 -------  -------
|       ||       |
|   N   ||   1   | ...and so on...
|       ||       |
 -------  -------
```

You can do this like so:

```
art_split = [art.split("\n") for art in dice_art]
zipped = zip(*art_split)

for elems in zipped:
    print("".join(elems))
#  -------  -------
# |       ||       |
# |   N   ||   1   |
# |       ||       |
#  -------  -------
```

**N.B.** You need to guarantee that each line is the same length in your output. If the lines of hyphens are shorter than the other, your alignment will be off.

In the future, if you provide the intended output, you can get much better responses.

Answer (score 0):

A join command should do it.

```
dice_art = ['ASCII0', 'ASCII1', 'ASCII2']
print(" ".join(dice_art))
```

The output would be:

```
ASCII0 ASCII1 ASCII2
```

Comment: That add's a space between each one of my dashes in the dice art ASCII representation.

Comment: The problem is that his strings aren't actually `['ASCII0', 'ASCII1', 'ASCII2']`. They're **multiline** and he wants them side by side. Otherwise, you'd be right—and so would everyone else.

Comment: Well, when I saw the question, there wasn't a real dice_art representation in his question... It is good that he updated his input though. Your answer would be what he want :)

Answer (score -1):

Change `print(dice_art[i], end='')` to:

- `print(dice_art[i], end=' '),` (Notice the space inbetween the two `'`s and the `,` after your previous code)

If you want to print the data dynamically, use the following syntax:

- `print(dice_art[i], sep=' ', end='', flush=True),`

Comment: This does not address the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry that code still prints on seperate lines, I have added the space in the string after end and the comma after the print statement.